# Is this a proper implementation of binary search? And has this program complexity of O(logn)?

Tags: c++

```
int szukaj2(int tab[], int n, int s){


if(n==1&&s==n){
    return 0;
} else if(n==1&&s!=tab[n]){
   return -1;
}
int m= n/2;


while(m>0){

    if(tab[m]==s){
        return m;
    }

    if(tab[m]<s){

        m=m+(m/2);
        cout<<"wieksze"<<endl;
    }

    if(tab[m]>s){

        m/=2;
        cout<<"mniejsze"<<endl;

    }
    m--;
}
return -1;
}
```

the complexity must be O(logn) so if its not, make sure to guide me to the right thinking. I will edit this every time if something aint right.

Comment: We don't like images of code here. Please edit question to include the code as text. Also, C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: Sorry, first time here

Comment: How are you calling this function? What is `n` and `s`?

Comment: _Is this a proper implementation of binary search_ would be no, since it doesn't work properly. If you're doing `while ( m > 0 )`, then you need to modify where `tab` points to when `s` is greater than `tab[m]`. An approach without modifying `tab` is to use a `left` and `right` variable, and do `while ( left < right )`

Comment: Instead of asking if it's a valid implementation, why not write a suite of unit tests against your implementation, then you can verify for yourself that it works.

Comment: @cigien n is the size of array and s is the element we are looking for

Comment: @StephenNewell i will remember that and try next time do it on my own, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary search (not tested):

```
int binary( int *array, int size, int value ) {
    int left = 0, right = size -1;

    while ( left < right ) {
        int mid = (int)( ( (long long)left + right ) / 2 );

        if ( array[mid] == value ) return mid;
        else if ( value < array[mid] ) right = mid - 1;
        else /* if ( value > array[mid] ) */ left = mid + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil, should be okay now?

Comment: thanks man, nice work, i have seen similar code, but i have tried to do something on my own, it seems like i need more practice